# Converting time stamp using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have a converted timestamp from utc to local and it look like below

2018-02-03T06:30:00.000Z .I need to display only 06:30 from the reponse.I tried using regex,but no luck.Is there any solution to convert it?

Comment: How did you convert it?

Comment: I tired to get the values after T and fore Z but no luck.

Comment: Show us your command, then we can correct it.

Comment: No need to be ashamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is wrong tool for it. You should convert the string to date and invoke `getUTCHours`, `getUTCMinutes` for getting the correct output.

```js
var date = new Date("2018-02-03T06:30:00.000Z");
console.log(date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes());
```

With formatting:

```js
var date = new Date("2018-02-03T06:30:00.000Z");
console.log(('0' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +  ('0' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2));
```

Comment: You don't get `06:30` with this approach. OP needs `06:30`

Comment: @GerardH.Pille It was just for formatting the output as Ankit wanted, originally it was pretty simple.

Comment: Come on, there must be a date method that gives you "06:30" immediately.

Comment: This is still a forceful solution

Comment: @AniketSahrawat  I gave it a try in my own answer.  But I was mistaken, javascript doesn't provide date output formatting, I mean, where you can specify the format yourself.

Comment: It seems illogical to parse a string to a Date, then use Date methods to get back values there were available in the original string. `'2018-02-03T06:30:00.000Z'.substr(11,5)` gives exactly the same result in way less code and very much more efficiently.

Comment: @RobG The `substr` might be more efficient, but the above approach is *not illogical*. How about incrementing the timestamp huh? Would you still depend on the `substr` and create your own classes and methods? If you say yes to creating your own logic, that would be *illogical*.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat—it's illogical to parse a string to a Date then back to a string just to get data that is easily available in the original string. Just because something is possible doesn't make it logical. The OP has no requirement to increment the values, and even if there was, it's not a given that using a Date is the best, or even a sensible, way.

Comment: @RobG *it's not a given that using a Date is the best, or even a sensible, way.*, **It is the best and sensible way to increment the date using default methods and Date class** because you don't need to worry about the things like Feb has 28 days, DST, changing timezone from ts, etc. Your comments does not make sense to me, high rep does not mean that you are correct.

Comment: @Aniket I think you are coming from Java background where parsing a date using regex or string methods is an offence because there is a rich api for date, remember the Date is JS is same as Calender class in Java: poorly designed. Anyways, you should add the implementation using regular expressions because the question demands it. **I will still support parsing a TS to Date Type in any condition.**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `regex` compulsorily here. You can use your own custom logic like this:

```js
var timeSt = '2018-02-03T06:30:00.000Z'
//split it using 'T' and get the second value of array
var arr = timeSt.split('T')[1];
//get the substring
var res = arr.substr(0,5);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why bother with *split*, why not `timeSt.substr(11,5)`?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answerers here. Regex is unnecessary, but since you are asking for it you can capture and replace your string with the capturing group `$1`

```
(\d\d:\d\d)
```

## [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mvn6nJ/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#match` like this:

```js
const date = "2018-02-03T06:30:00.000Z";
const [timepart] = date.match(/\d+:\d+/) || [];
console.log(timepart);
```

Comment: The output of your solution is ["06:30"], but what I need is only 06:30 withou brackets.

Comment: Then just skip the array initialization and get what you need.

Comment: Did you notice the destructuring assignment?

Comment: Otherwise I don't understand your comment. The output is "06:30" when you run the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `moment.js`.

There is one little problem. You wanted to convert UTC to local time but your string still represents UTC time. The last 'Z' means "zero hour offset". If the 'Z' is invalid tag and the time is actually local you can remove the last 'Z' with `slice(0, -1)`. You can check ISO 8601 Data elements and interchange formats https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 to see further about the format.

```
var moment = require('moment');
console.log( moment( '2018-02-03T06:30:00.000Z'.slice(0, -1) ).format('HH:MM') );
```

If the last 'Z' character is indeed valid one and you still need to convert 06:30 UTC to local time just remove the `slice`

```
console.log( moment('2018-02-03T06:30:00.000Z').format('HH:MM') );
```

This will print a converted local time.
`moment.js` can simplify your date and time manipulations. Check https://momentjs.com for docs.

If you use node.js

```
$ npm install moment
```

to install moment.js node module.

Comment: Using moment I have done it. I was trying with regex.Thanks anyway :)